# Unit roots Dickey Fuller test question

Tags: time-series, references, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I've been searching in bibliography about this test applied to an ARMA(p,q) model, and find out that every single book states the null hypothesis as "1 is a root of the operator". I was wondering if that was merely a simplification, or that's the test?

I'm asking this question because it seems to me that the null hypothesis must be "there exists a root with absolute value less or equal to one".

I'm new in this subject, and any information or book recommendation is appreciated.

Comment: So are you wondering if the root can be >|1|?

Comment: No, I'm wondering if rejecting the null hypothesis "1 is a root of the operator" implies that the operator has all the roots outside the unit circle,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question is about the maths involved in the test. I don't understand why rejecting the Null Hypothesis $H_{0}:\gamma=0$ implies that the poynomial expression associated to the model has all roots outside the unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simple special case of the augmented Diskey-Fuller test equation:

$$ \Delta x_t = \gamma x_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t $$

(I have skipped all other potential right-hand-side terms since they are just nuisance with respect to your question).

You reject the null hypothesis of the test when $\gamma$ divided by its standard error is sufficiently *negative*. If $\gamma$ indeed is negative, the process is stationary. If $\gamma$ is zero, the process has a unit root. If $\gamma$ is positive, the process is explosive. Hence, when the null hypothesis is *not* rejected, the process may be either a unit-root process or an explosive one. (For the sake of formality I have to note that we do not accept a null hypothesis, we may just fail to reject it.) Addressing your actual question,

> I'm wondering if rejecting the null hypothesis "1 is a root of the operator" implies that the operator has all the roots outside the unit circle

the answer is yes, the null hypothesis is rejected when the roots are *outside* the unit circle (rather than the more general case that they are *not on* the unit circle).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Richard, but maybe I didn't express myself correctly.    
My Null Hypothesis is $H_{0}: " |\gamma+1| \geq 1 " $. 

While I was looking for the test in the internet and books, I saw that a $\gamma=0$ is being used to run the test. The question is. Why is that correct?

Comment: I guess your question is more about formal references than the nature of the test. For me the test equation and the test statistic reveals all I need to know about it. But OK, it is still a valid question.

Comment: Does rejecting $\gamma=0$ mean that there is one unit root (in the first-order lag) or that there is at least one unit root?

Comment: @jmb, I think *at least* one.